# For partition key queries on composite keys, what is the cost?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, database-partitioning, composite-key

Let's say we have a composite key : `name` (partition key) and `timestamp` (sort key)

If I query `name` with the latest `timestamp`, would I bear the cost of all entries inside the partition, or only the latest entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a [`Query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) with [`Limit=1`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-Limit) and [`ScanIndexForward=False`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-ScanIndexForward) then you will get the latest value and only pay to read 1 item.

```
aws dynamodb query \
--table-name my-table \
--key-condition-expression "#pk = :pk" \
--expression-attribute-values '{":pk":{"S":"leeroy"}' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#pk":"name"}' \
--no-scan-index-forward \
--limit 1
```

Likewise, if you know the `name` and `timestamp` you can do a [`GetItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) and only pay to read 1 item.

```
aws dynamodb get-item \
--table-name my-table \
--key '{"name": {"S": "leeroy"},"timestamp": {"S": "2023-01-01T20:00:000"}}'
```